# Why this simple PWM doesn't work in xc8

Tags: c, pic, pwm, xc8

I know there are a lot of examples in internet, but what does need this code to work ?

frecuency oscillator = 4mhz

periode = 0.25us

duty_cicle = 250

Prescale = 16

PR2 = 124

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pic16f88.h>

#pragma config FOSC = HS  // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // RA5/MCLR/VPP Pin Function Select bit (RA5/MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB4/PGM pin has digital I/O function, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EE Memory Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection off)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

void main ()
{
     while (1)
     {
            CCP1CON = 0x2C; /*activate PWM mode*/
            PR2 = 0x7C;    /*124 (DECIMAL)*/
            T2CON = 0X06; /*prescale 16 */
            CCPR1L = 0X3E;

     }    
}
```

I want to see :

Period of PWM = 2ms

Dutycicle = 1ms

Sincerilly
NIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off topic:
Don't include pic16f88.h, it's included by xc.h.

Little more off topic:
If you use a more modern part (e.g. [PIC16f1619](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC16F1619)), you can use the MPLAB Code Configurator to generate the TMR2 and CCP code for you.  It'll also cost less and have more flash/ram.  That device is on the [curiosity board](http://www.microchip.com/promo/curiosity) ($20).

On Topic:
Your first stop is the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30487D.pdf#page=4).

The PWM section has the [setup for PWM operation](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30487D.pdf#page=85).

Step1:
The [timer 2](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30487D.pdf#page=79) takes Fosc/4 as an input, which is 1mhz in your case.
Target frequency is 500Hz.  1e6/500 = 2k.
I'd suggest a prescaler of 16, and pr value of 125.  This will give you exactly 500Hz.

Step2:
We want a 50% duty cycle.  CCP1L floor(125/2) = 62. CCP1X:CCP1Y = 0.5 * 4 = 2.

Step 3:
Clear the tris bit.

Step4 and 5:
Turn it on

```
// Step 1
TMR2ON = 0;
TOUTPS = 0;
T2CKPS = 2;
PR2 = 250U;

// Step 2
CCP1L = 62U;
CCP1X = 1;
CCP1Y = 0;

// Step 3
TRISB3 = 0;

// Step 4
TMR2ON = 1;

// Step 5
CCP1M = 0xC;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet states:

> In Pulse-Width Modulation (PWM) mode, the CCP1 pin
>   produces up to a 10-bit resolution PWM output. Since
>   the CCP1 pin is multiplexed with the PORTB data latch,
>   the TRISB bit must be cleared to make the CCP1
>   pin an output.

So you must set the TRIS bit for the CCP1 pin to output:

```
TRISB &= ~(1 << 3); //Clear bit RB3/CCP1 in TRISB, makes PORTB3/CCP1 output.
```

This assumes `CCPMX: CCP1 Pin Selection bit` in the configuration word is clear. If set, then CCP1 is on RB0 in stead of RB3 but since I see no mention of CCPMX in your configuration pragma's i assume it is cleared.

Comment: Hi . I doesn't work. Even though your instruccion is executed by XC8 . I've put your instruccion after "while (1)". What would be the problem ?